# Error Installing automapper -version:4.1.0

Tags: nuget

I am using visual studio 2013 
Package Manager Console Host Version 2.8.60610.756
I am trying to install antomapper version 4.1 using this command 
install-package automapper -version:4.1.0

but I am getting this error message:

> The source at nuget.org [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is
>   unreachable. Falling back to NuGet Local Cache at
>   C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache Install-Package : Unable
>   to find version '4.1.0' of package 'automapper'. At line:1 char:16
>   + install-package <<<<  automapper -version:4.1.0
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Please help me resolve this issue
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message you quoted:

> The source at nuget.org [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is unreachable.

Your computer cannot reach nuget.  Either your network connectivity is down, or nuget is having a temporary outage.

Comment: this error is coming since the very first day I installed visual studio, any suggestion for troubleshooting ?